# Are there any plans or ongoing work of supporting Apple T2 chip SSD?

Tags: ssd, macbook-pro, apple

Are there any plans or ongoing work of supporting Apple T2 chip SSD/hard disks?
I cannot find any information online about Linux/Ubuntu being developing the necessary drivers for this and wanted to know if someone knows any details about it.

Comment: I guess it's not supported, no : https://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/3065755/apples-t2-chip-is-blocking-linux-from-booting-on-new-mac-hardware maybe one day, after all it's basically just a SOC. nothing too special. should be doeable if anyone considers it's worth the hassle (it's doubtfull because why use mac hardware when now even it's thiness isn't winning any trophies, it's got nothing left going for it, it's been beaten in every imaginable field and at a cheaper price)

Comment: It's not NVMe compliant so Linux Kernel won't support it. Apple has released a Windows driver for it so it's not totally Mac only. Still I'm voting to close as it's a hardware question: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202567

Comment: Dear Tatsu, the issue I have is that my company provides the hardware and they provide only MBP, as per a company policy. However I hate MacOS so I'd be glad to install Linux on it. However... there the T2 is unsupported...

Comment: @ubuntuUssser For now, you can use Linux on macOS using virtualization.

Comment: I tried that but the performance is extremely low, I cannot even click through the stuff or type in fluently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux kernel team is not going to support Apple T2 chip. The support has been requested in the [kernel’s bug tracker](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202567) and the current status is [`WILL_NOT_FIX`](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/Bugzilla/Fields/Status/RESOLVED#WONTFIX).

Details are given in a [comment to the bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202567#c1):

> It's not NVMe compliant, hence it won't work with the in-kernel NVMe driver. This is not a Linux bug, it's Apple doing their usual thing. If someone wants to work on this, be my guest.

Since there is no public documentation for T2, Linux kernel developers have refused to try to support this hardware. However, unexpected things may happen and the support for Apple T2 *may* appear *sometimes*.

> “While there’s life, there’s hope.”
>   [Marcus Tullius Cicero](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/253109-while-there-s-life-there-s-hope)

Comment: The Linux kernel team doesn't usally deal with writing drivers for specific pieces of hardware, period. Besides, OP had filled the request as a block layer bug, and fairly the maintainer said that wasn't his job. A driver already exist [since months](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=NVMe-Patches-LKML-Apple-Mac) anyway.